# getting permission error when trying locust -V

Tags: python, pip, locust

I just installed locust with `pip install locust`, it was installed at `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.
The problem is if I try to get the version of it with `locust -V` i get a permission denied error.

`> which locust`
`locust not found`
`> type locust`
`locust not found`
`> locust`
`zsh: permission denied: locust`

`~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` is in the PATH

`ls -lF $(which locust)` and `head -1 $(which locust)` has no result since `which locust` cannot find it.

If reinstalling:

```
❯ pip install locust                                                                      

Requirement already satisfied: locust in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from locust) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.6.7 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (5.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Cors>=3.0.10 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (3.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-BasicAuth>=0.2.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack>=0.6.2 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: geventhttpclient>=1.5.1 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=22.2.1 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (22.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask>=2.0.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ConfigArgParse>=1.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: roundrobin>=0.0.2 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (0.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: gevent>=20.9.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (21.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from locust) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Flask-Cors>=3.0.10->locust) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from geventhttpclient>=1.5.1->locust) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from geventhttpclient>=1.5.1->locust) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask>=2.0.0->locust) (8.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask>=2.0.0->locust) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask>=2.0.0->locust) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gevent>=20.9.0->locust) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.event in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gevent>=20.9.0->locust) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet<2.0,>=1.1.0; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gevent>=20.9.0->locust) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from gevent>=20.9.0->locust) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /home/marcosdipaolo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask>=2.0.0->locust) (2.0.1)
```

Comment: `which locust` ? `ls -lF $(which locust)` ? `head -1 $(which locust)` ?

Comment: @phd question updated

Comment: can you try running `type locust`? Maybe there is some alias or something...

Comment: question updated @Cyberwiz

Comment: that makes no sense. maybe your shell is messed up? have you tried logging off and back on again? Anything funny/advanced in your shell startup files? I'm not very familiar with zsh...

Comment: Maybe check all the entries in your $PATH for a file called `locust`?

Comment: nop, no mentions of locust there

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your help.
Problem is locust command is installed at `~/.local/bin/locust`, and that wasn't in the path.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` should not be on your path.

I think the problem is that zsh finds the locust package ***folder*** (at `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/`) and tries to execute it.

pip should install locust as a command (at for example `/usr/local/bin/locust`). Try reinstalling and check for any errors while installing, as pip should log a warning if it was installed somewhere that isn't in your path.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Cyberwiz , question updated with reinstalling response, no locust at `/usr/local/bin`